# Solving recurrence relation where the $f(n)$ has some constant factor $k$ where $0 < k < 1$

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I am trying to see if a recurrence relation where $f(n)$ has some constant factor $k$, e.g. $f(n)=kn$ where $0 < k < 1$, is $O(n)$. I am reaching a different result depending which route I take. Given the following recurrence relation:

$$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+f(n)$$
$$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+kn$$
Since $0 < k < 1$, we can represent $kn=n^c$, where $0 < c < 1$

This falls under the [case 1 of the Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), because $a=2, b=2$, and therefore $log_b a = log_2 2 = 1 > c$.

It's $O(n)$.

But if I try to unfold the recurrence:
$$\begin{split}T(n) & = 2T(\frac{n}{2})+kn \\
& = 4T(\frac{n}{4})+2kn \\
& = 8T(\frac{n}{8})+3kn \\
& = ... \\
& = 2^cT(\frac{n}{2^c})+ckn \\
\end{split}$$

When $\frac{n}{2^c}=1$, $n=2^c$, then $log_2 n = c$.

So now it's $T(n) = nT(1) + kn log_2 n$, which is $O(n log_2 n)$. Now I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is where you claim that $kn=n^c$ where $0<c<1$.  This is not correct.    Even when $k<1$, it is still the case that $kn=\Theta(n)$; it is not $O(n^c)$ for any $c<1$.  (Check the definition of big-O notation.)

Comment: But I can pick $c, k ∈ R$ where $kn = n^c$, right? For example $k=0.1, n=100, c=0.5$ Is this not true for all $n, c$, and $k$?

Comment: @garbagecollector, no.  I suggest spending some time with the definition of big-O notation.  ($c$ is not allowed to depend on $n$.)  This platform isn't well-suited for interactive tutoring, unfortunately.